# Why isn't remote mobile app testing more popular?

Tags: android, testing, mobile

[Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/) and [Keynote DeviceAnywhere](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/index.aspx) are both seemingly valuable tools. They allow the user to connect remotely to a variety of mobile devices for testing purposes.

My question is why is it that these companies and their tools aren't more popular among independent mobile developers, and especially Android developers, who I'm sure can't afford to own tens of phones to test on.

After searching the web I found very little support anywhere from mobile developers.

I plan on purchasing some hours to test the software out myself but I would like to know what anyone else's opinions are.

Are these products poorly made?
Are they just not practical?
Do they cost more than they increase your profits?

Comment: The answers are great but I really only have 2 opinions and I want to see if there is a general consensus. Please, if you agree with whats been said, speak up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfecto is 250 bucks for 10 hours of testing and I cannot find the cost on Keynote's website.    That is why I am not using Keynote, and will not recommend it to anyone.

So back to Perfecto, 250 bucks for 10 hours seems like a good deal.  I'm just skeptical of how it works.  The implication is that you are remotely testing on "the cloud", but hopefully everyone here knows that word doesn't actually mean anything-- it's just a set of servers...

So, buzz words aside, how could this possibly work?  The implication is they have all these various android devices running "in the cloud," but that doesn't make sense.  Maybe they are running emulators, and have tailored them to reflect the various devices?  I haven't done this, but I have seen articles about manipulating *.ini files to make an AVD reflect an actual device.  And if so, that doesn't seem worth the effort and/or cost...

And honestly, since you asked, I have not and probably never will use a similar service.  I have two devices and an emulator, and am comfortable with that level of testing.  If there are issues in the field, I get a crash report and can fix them.  I don't mind being reactive if the issue is only on a specific device.

Comment: I got the impression that they use ACTUAL devices, not emulators [cite](http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/services/handsets.html). But maybe I am wrong. Can anyone confirm this?

Also, there are some issues on devices that are not manifested by a crash. For instance when I turn off bitmap interpolation it renders differently on different devices.

Comment: it looks like you are right and my initial assumption is wrong.  But this just raises more questions.  Why do they say it is "cloud" based when it seems you are just remotely accessing different international devices?  Seems like an overly aggressive marketing team.  They also seem to require you to use their proprietary "ScriptOnce" to write test cases.  This is generally a bad idea, because if this company goes out of business or you want to change your test plan, you are locked in to this propriety format and out of luck.  I am hesitant, but at the end of the day it's your decision.

Answer (score 0):

That is a question that is hard to answer with 1 answer.

One thing is that it takes time and if there is one thing many app developers don't have it is the time to wait. Don't get me wrong, its great to test apps properly on every single device (there is some very anoing quirks on some of the phones) but for most apps this just isn't that important. Having 3-5 real devices is more than enough for most normal app development.